# Is it possible to declare a 2d array class member inside the constructor with a for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, 2d

Currently I have this

```
//gameboard.h

class GameBoard
{ 
public:
    GameBoard(bool showShips);
    ~GameBoard();
    void draw();
    void placeShipStart(int x, int y);
    void placeShipEnd(int ship, int x, int y);
private:
    bool defaultShowShips;
    Field playerBoard[10][10];
    vector<Ship*> ships[5];
};

//gameboard.cpp

GameBoard::GameBoard(bool showShips)
{ 
    defaultShowShips = showShips; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            xyzCoord ul, lr;
            ul.x = j * 5.0f;
            ul.y = i * 5.0f;
            ul.z = 2.0f;
            lr.x = j * 5.0f + 5.0f;
            lr.y = i * 5.0f + 5.0f;
            lr.z = 0.0f;
            playerBoard[i][j] = Field(ul, lr);
        }
};
```

The way it is right now it's telling me that I need to have a default constructor for field. I'm trying to accomplish initializing each position in a different position. Am I doing this completely wrong? I've seen the vector of vectors approach. If possible I would like to avoid that because it wasn't working for me earlier.

Comment: Can we please see your `Field` class? When it says **default constructor**, it means that all of the variables declared in the constructor function declaration must be provided with **default** values. I see your `Field` constructor has at least 2 parameters of type `xyzCoord`. So, either provide default values in the parameter list (I can show you when I see your class). Or add a second constructor which takes no parameters.

Comment: Is it not possible to initiate these values without using a default constructor? Like can I allocate the space and then construct each one individually?

Comment: See my updated answer. Seeing the constructors for xyzCoord would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing here to a certain degree, but try this:

```
Field::Field()
{
    // Provided default values to your two member variables
}

Field::Field(xyzCoord ul, xyzCoord lr)
{
    // Populate your two member variables with the passed in values
}
```

The first constructor will be your default as it has no parameters.

I hope this helps. Apologies if I miss-understood your question.

**Update**

The alternative is:

This in the header:

```
Field::Field(xyzCoord ul = xyzCoord(), xyzCoord lr = xyzCoord())
```

This in the source:

```
Field::Field(xyzCoord ul /*xyzCoord()*/, xyzCoord lr /*xyzCoord()*/)
{
    // Populate your two member variables with the passed in values
}
```

I am conveying the principles. Without seeing the Field and xyzCoord class I can't see what the suitable declarations would be. With this last approach the constructor how provides default values for each parameter.

See this [default constructor](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#default-ctor) topic for more information. In part it mentions:

[image: constructors]

Comment: I want to avoid being able to create a Field object without the ul and lr's. Is it possible or am I barking up the wrong tree? I want to initiate these values in the constructor of the gameboard.

Comment: @VincentJenkins I have updated my response to show you how you can use your constructor and provide default values.